# Issues installing Swup using npm with Zurb Foundation

Tags: node.js, npm, zurb-foundation

I am having problems getting Swup to work with foundation.

So far I have...

1. Installed via npm.
2. Created a new js/lib/dependencies file
3. Added the import to the foundation app.js
4. Added it to the config.yml (Some guess work here - probably doesn’t
   need to be in all those places)
5. Created the css and added it appropriately.
6. I also changed swup animation selector from 'transition-' to 'swup
   transition' as recommended.

So after doing all that i get the last image 7, and If i click on one I more or less get this text. Cannot GET /index.html:content.

I hope some one can make sense of, not only this question, but a solution.

[image: 1]
[image: 2a]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]
[image: 5a]
[image: 5b]
[image: 5c]
[image: 6]
[image: 7]

Answer (score 0):

There is no export in lib/dependencies.js. You might want to use a normal require or export the swup instance from there (which is in some cases not needed when you use `require`).

Comment: Hej Daniel (Great name ; ) - Thanks for your response. I tried the following but no joy - any other ideas?  // custom dependencies

import Swup from 'swup';

export const swup = new Swup();